# Permission denied to Git despite valid SSH authentication

Tags: windows, git, ssh

This morning my Windows git client surprised me with

```
> git pull

git@github.xxx.net: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

This happens despite the fact SSH authentication with GitHub works

```
>ssh git@github.xxx.net
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
Hi dzieciou! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
Connection to github.xxx.net closed.
```

Would could be the reason? I have all necessary permission to access this particular project.

Comment: Did you use `git@github.com:username/repo` url as remote? Did you check that you have access to the repo in the browser?

Comment: @MaartenDev This is GitHub Enterprise, but shouldn't matter: URL is correct `git@github.xxx.net:organization/repo.git` and I have access to this repo both from Web browser and from Ubuntu. Looks like some integration problem between Git client and SSH on Windows. It used to work yesterday.

Comment: Did you try the debugging steps on: https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/error-permission-denied-publickey to verify that the correct key file is used?

Answer (score 0):

First, check what the same `git pull` does after typying

```
set GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -Tv"
```

And compare it with `ssh -Tv git@github.xxx.net`

Second, make sure there is no other `GIT` environment variable. To list them:

```
set GIT
```

This is to check if there is a `GIT_SSH` environment variable, referencing a different ssh as the one you would be using by default with Git for Windows.